# Get MKLocalSearch to only return places

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview

I have looked at the documentation and can't find a way to use MKLocalSearch to only return areas. For example I want the search to search world wide for cities, towns, villages & counties but not return any businesses or hotels etc. Is that possible?

Thanks

D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use  predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *noBusiness = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"business.uID == 0"];
NSMutableArray *itemsWithoutBusinesses = [response.mapItems mutableCopy];
[itemsWithoutBusinesses filterUsingPredicate:noBusiness];
```

Example local search code is also adding, which will solve your problem.

```
-(void)issueLocalSearchLookup:(NSString *)searchString {
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.location.coordinate, 30000, 30000);
self.localSearchRequest = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
self.localSearchRequest.region = region;
self.localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchString;
self.localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:self.localSearchRequest];

[self.localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"LocalSearch failed with error: %@", error);
        return;
    } else {
        for(MKMapItem *mapItem in response.mapItems){
            [self.data addObject:mapItem];
        }
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

}

Comment: I am confused, does apple provide ID's for business returned by MKLocalSearch?

Comment: After some digging this is a private framework using the GEOBusiness class.

Answer (score 0):

based on your requirement change the key parameter for addressDictionary.

```
      for(MKMapItem *mapItem in response.mapItems)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",mapItem.placemark.addressDictionary[@"Street"]);
}
```

Comment: How does this restrict the MKLocalSearch results to "places"?